# When a force applies to a rigid body at point, then does every part of the body experience the same kind of force?

Tags: statics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose that a rigid body is static under the action of several forces that are applied at different part of the body. Then is it true that if one divides the body into small pieces, then each piece experiences a kind of forces that are all identical to what the whole does except being scaled?

Comment: If the body is rigid and static then no net force is acting at any point. What happens instead is that [stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28mechanics%29) is created. And no, this stress is seldom uniform - see [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Plastic_Protractor_Polarized_05375.jpg) for example.

Comment: @lemon I'm talking about load condition

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: @lemon I mean the question is whether one piece would experience exactly the same kind of forces as the whole except being scaled.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to speak of forces in this context, only stress...